# Update Azure Windows 10 VM to Anniversary Update

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, azure

I'm trying to setup a VM in azure that runs Windows 10 anniversary update (oddly I couldn't find any VMs running that at this time). I picked the available Windows 10 Enterprize (I think was it was version 1511). Downloaded the ISO for 1607 from MSDN. Mounted it and ran the setup.exe then the machine rebooted. Now I'm stuck because of the First Time Experience Prompts. See ScrreenShot[image: First Boot Prompt]

So the question is; how do I get past this prompt OR how to I skip the whole thing and just get a azure VM with the Anniversary Update? Remote desktop doesn't work at this point (because the machine isn't done booting?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, only fresh install will get this prompt. Please follow [this guide](https://neosmart.net/wiki/windows-10-repair-installation/#Repair_Installing_Windows_10) to perform a repair installation(upgrade) with the ISO you download.

If you do want a fresh installation. Then you need to customize your ISO to include a answer file so that the OOBE phase can be passed automatically.

It's pretty complex if it is your first time to use MDT. You may need to try it several times to find out the setting which is suitable for you.

[Create a Windows 10 reference image](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/create-a-windows-10-reference-image?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Settings for Automating OOBE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/hh825198.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

The Azure images are using Windows 10 Enterprise N (N means there's no multimedia enhancements like Media Player). If you try to update to the **non-N** version, you'll get an install prompt when the setup restarts and you won't be able to get further on Azure.

If you update using the "Windows 10 Enterprise **N** x64 en-us" iso, and keep all the setup defaults, you'll update without any problem on Azure.

If you want to add the multimedia enhancements back to the N version, you can install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/49919 (1511) or https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/53356 (1607 anniversary edition).